# Where is the proper place to put domain logic to update a child of an aggregate root?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, aggregates

Is it a best practice to update children of an aggregate root directly, or only through its aggregate root? For example, which is preferred:

```
Order.UpdateOrderLineQuantity(orderLine, quantity);
```

or

```
Order.OrderLines[0].UpdateQuantity(quantity);
```

Any guidance in this department would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

An aggregate root is an object that encapsulates related child objects, so you should use the first technique.

In the same way that callers shouldn't care if Order IDs are stored as integers or byte arrays, they shouldn't care or know whether it uses `OrderLines` or `HideousLegacyObjects` to store and manipulate order details.

Comment: It makes sense for the add, but I primarily concerned with lines that are already part of the order. Is it better to let the order handle the update?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the example, but it doesn't change the gist of my answer: the order should still handle the update.

Comment: This could end up polluting the AR API, the AR will need to expose behavior for each of its entities, is this acceptable?

Comment: @Sudarshan, it's not just acceptable, it's practically the whole point of an aggregate root. If you find you have too many operations, you might want to think about dividing the aggregate into multiple bounded contexts.